# ¿Por qué mis columnas no aparecen una junta a la otra?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy realizando una página web en la cual tengo tengo un una clase `row` que contiene diferentes columnas, como se muestra en el código:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
    <p class="shoppTitleform" style="color: #ff9012 !important">¿Qué Shopper eres tú?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Amigo?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra supermercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Horario rotativo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 20%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Vecino?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra minimercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Eliges tu horario</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que las columnas `md6` ocupan un espacio mayor y no se muestran una al lado de la otra si no que se muestran una debajo de otra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ven el a imagen la segunda columnas `md6` pasa a bajo en vez de estar al lado. ¿Cómo puedo corregir ese error? Cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con Angular.

Éste es el resultado deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Éste es un problema relativamente común al migrar de Bootstrap 3 a Bootstrap 4.

En Bootstrap 3, el sistema de grid se basa en columnas flotantes con un ancho definido (se puede ver en el [código no minificado de Bootstrap 3](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css)). Así, aunque tuvieras columnas directamente dentro de otras columnas -[que no es lo recomendado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting)- se seguirían dividiendo bien.

Por eso con la versión 3 de Bootstrap, **tu código sin cambios** funciona bien:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
    <p class="shoppTitleform" style="color: #ff9012 !important">¿Qué Shopper eres tú?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Amigo?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra supermercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Horario rotativo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 20%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Vecino?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra minimercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Eliges tu horario</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora, en Bootstrap 4 se cambió el [sistema de grid y pasó a usarse flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/): el `.row` tiene `display:flex` y las columnas tienen un `flex` que indica el ancho (se puede ver en el [código no minificado de Bootstrap 4](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css)).

Así, para evitar que las columnas se pongan unas encima de las otras en lugar de unas al lado de las otras (el problema que estás viendo), debes siempre tener un `.row` como contenedor (o padre) de las columnas, como se indica en [la documentación (traducción mía)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting):

> Para anidar tu contenido con el grid por defecto, añade un nuevo `.row` y grupo de columnas `.col-sm-*` dentro de la columas `.col-sm-*` ya existente. Las filas anidadas deberían incluir un grupo de columnas que sumen 12 o menos (no es necesario que uses todas las 12 columnas disponibles).

La solución entonces sería [hacer lo que te sugiere Armando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/176894/250) en su respuesta: añadir un `.row` dentro de las columnas que van a ser subdivididas en más columnas:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
    <p class="shoppTitleform" style="color: #ff9012 !important">¿Qué Shopper eres tú?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Amigo?</p>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra supermercado</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Horario rotativo</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 20%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Vecino?</p>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra minimercado</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Eliges tu horario</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otra opción sería añadir la clase `row` a la columna que va a contener más columnas, aunque quizás no sería la más recomendada porque podría generar problemas con los `padding` y la separación entre las columnas:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
    <p class="shoppTitleform" style="color: #ff9012 !important">¿Qué Shopper eres tú?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Amigo?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra supermercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Horario rotativo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 20%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">¿Shopper Vecino?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra minimercado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Eliges tu horario</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left;    font-size: 2em;">Compra y entrega</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Registrame</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por compartir tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho.
saludos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando un **contenedor** y **div.row** independientes:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: -3%; text-align: center;">
        <p class="shoppTitleform" style="color: #ff9012 !important">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp" >Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 20%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()" >Lorem ipsum dolor</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p class="shoppTitleform typeShopp">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="descriptTypeShopp" style="color: #666;float: left; font-size: 2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 40%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 40%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="btn_shopper btnReg btnmovilReg" onclick="scrollWin()">Lorem ipsum dolor</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```